# Fonts not loading in React Native App built with Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

all,

I am new to react native, currently, I am having an issue with customized fonts usage.
My issue is: font files not exists though I already put my fonts files in directory: ./assets/fonts
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srb7W.png)

I am following steps of Expo documentation of using customized fonts, which is installing expo-font and using useFont hook. My code as following:

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import AuthStack from './routes/authStack'
import store, { persistor } from './store'
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font'
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading'
import { Font } from 'expo'
import Loading from './components/loading'


function App() {

  const [fontLoaded] = useFonts({
    Arial: require('./assets/fonts/ARIAL.TTF'),
    ArialBold: require('./assets/fonts/ARIALBD.TTF'),
    BlairMd: require('./assets/fonts/BlairMdITCTTMediumFont.ttf'),
  })
  console.log('app font loaded====', fontLoaded)
  return fontLoaded ? (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <AuthStack />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  ) : (
    <AppLoading />
  )
```

Everything looks fine for me, so I am thinking might because of project setting reasons so I have tried to restart the project, uninstall all packages and install them again, clear cache by running expo r -c. But nothing works.

I appreciate if anyone can help, thank you

Comment: I tried to use the font link URL instead of require function, which looks like {Arial: 'http://arialfontlinkaddress'}, it can correctly load the font. Which means the require function is not getting the font, but I still do not know why, if anyone has any solution, please share with me, thank you

Comment: Update for the question: I have 4 font files under my fonts folder: Arial(ARIAL.TTF), Arial bold(ARIALBD.TTF), Blair(BlairMdITCTTMediumFont.ttf), spaceage(FONTspaceage.ttf) I can use require function to load blair and spaceage font, but not the other two, thats very weird. If anyone has any clue, please share with me, thank you

Comment: How do you use font link url?

Answer (score 0):

```
//USE THIS INSTEAD
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
function App() {

  const [fontLoaded] = useFonts({
    Arial: require('./assets/fonts/ARIAL.TTF'),
    ArialBold: require('./assets/fonts/ARIALBD.TTF'),
    BlairMd: require('./assets/fonts/BlairMdITCTTMediumFont.ttf'),
  });
   
  if(!fontLoaded){
      return null; //AppLoading is deprecated
   };
 
  return(
    <Provider store={store}>
     //Stack Screen to be loaded
    </Provider>
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I was able to fix it by naming my object key the same as the file name

eg:-

```
const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    PoppinsRegular: require('./../../assets/Fonts/PoppinsRegular.otf'),
    });
```